# Dealing with type annotations for isString instances

Tags: yesod

I know that in some cases I have to provide a type annotation for something that's an isString instance, but I'm not entirely sure where and why I have to do it.

I have a form that I want to render with Bootstrap3 per the [following documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.3.8.2/docs/src/Yesod-Form-Bootstrap3.html#bootstrapSubmit)

In my form, if I just leave it as `bootstrapSubmit "Register"`, I will get the following:

```
No instance for (Data.String.IsString msg0)
  arising from the literal `"Register"'
The type variable `msg0' is ambiguous
```

If I change it to `(bootstrapSubmit ("add" :: BootstrapSubmit Text))`, it does compile. How come it doesn't work for me like the documentation shows?

Here is some other examples I'm confused about:

The [bfs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.3.8.2/docs/src/Yesod-Form-Bootstrap3.html#bfs) function, which I wanted to use as follows in my form:

```
    areq intField (bfs "Weight") Nothing
```

to get my fields to get the extra `form-control` class. Same story with `No instance for...` Changing it to `areq intField (bfs ("Weight"::Text)) Nothing` fixes the type problem.

Why doesn't this work for me as advertised without the type-annotations?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `OverloadedStrings` pragma, like at the top of the [Bootstrap3 module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.3.8.2/docs/src/Yesod-Form-Bootstrap3.html)?

Comment: I just tried adding it in but it didn't help, same error. I was under the impression though that OverloadedStrings is active pretty much everywhere in my project, just like TemplateHaskell and various other extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The msg in `bootstrapSubmit msg` or `bfs msg` must be a renderable msg, instance of class [RenderMessage](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization#internationalization_rendermessage_typeclass).

```
bootstrapSubmit
    :: (RenderMessage site msg, HandlerSite m ~ site, MonadHandler m)
    => BootstrapSubmit msg -> AForm m ()

bfs :: RenderMessage site msg => msg -> FieldSettings site
```

This can be

- a String literal with type Text (in-code messages are not a good policy) - OverloadedStrings should work here.
- a localizable I18 msg constructor of the form MsgMyMessage where MyMessage must have an entry in the file `messages/en.msg`